# Download servlet's doGet() throws NullPointerException

Tags: java, servlets, java-ee-6

I am developing a simple web application in which client should be able to download a pdf file by clicking a hyperlink from the HTML page.I am using MVC pattern.Below is my code for Servlet :

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
{
    response.setContentType("application/pdf");
    ServletContext ctx = getServletContext();
    InputStream is = ctx.getResourceAsStream("/abc.pdf");

    int read = 0;
    byte [] bytes = new byte[1024];

    OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();
    while((read = is.read(bytes)) != -1)
    {
        os.write(bytes, 0, read);
    }
    os.flush();
    os.close();
}
```

**I am using Apache Tomcat 6.0**

Below is the error i am getting :

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet download threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at BookDownloaderServlet.doGet(BookDownloaderServlet.java:41)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
```

**abc.pdf is correctly placed under application contex** . Still cant find a reason for this exception.
kindly help.
thanks in advance

Comment: It would help if you could tell us which line in your snippet is 41 to exactly locate where the NPE appeared.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely this line is your problem:

```
InputStream is = ctx.getResourceAsStream("/abc.pdf");
```

`is` is assigned to `null`. It throws an exception here:

```
is.read(bytes)
```

Looks like `abc.pdf` file does not exist in the root of your CLASSPATH.

Comment: placing abc.pdf inside webcontents solved my problem..I am using Eclipse Indigo and hence earlier i was placing abc.pdf exactly under my project name...I think there is no need to keep that file in classpath..thanks for the clue

Answer (score 0):

try changing `InputStream is = ctx.getResourceAsStream("/abc.pdf");` to `InputStream is = ctx.getResourceAsStream("abc.pdf");`

remove `/`